# Xcode llvm link static library based on defined macro

Tags: iphone, ios, linker, llvm

I am building an iOS app where I want to be able to start my app in a demo mode with mocked connections. I use a static library for the mocking. However I don't want this library to be linked in my release build for the app store. I am looking for a solution to this problem.

The best solution I could imagine would be if I can define a compiler macro like this:

```
#define TEST_ENVIRONMENT 1
```

and if this macro is 1, the library would be linked. But I don't know how to setup the linking for this. Is there anything similar that would work?

I know I could create a new configuration in Xcode and manually add the -l option for the library for this configuration but this means that it can easily happen that one edits a build setting and forgets to edit the test configuration as well, or vise versa.

Best regards,
Michael